# Add Column name from Row Data

Tags: mysql, asp.net

i have one table

```
stock   idWarehouse  Warehousname  idorder
-492    1               xyz          1
-24     3               abc          1
-492    1               xyz          2 
-24     3               abc          2
```

i want result in following form

```
xyz  abc    idorder
-492  -24     1
-492  -24     2
```

Comment: How many different variations for `Warehousname` may happen ?

Comment: If your warehouses are known ahead of time this isn't that hard. If they aren't. It's best done in the application

Comment: Only 2 different variation of warehouse happen

Answer (score 1):

If `Warehousname` has limited set of values, you can do this:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN Warehousname='xyz' THEN stock END) AS xyz,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Warehousname='abc' THEN stock END) AS abc,
       idorder
FROM TableName
GROUP BY idorder
```

Sample result:

```
xyz     abc     idorder
-492    -24     1
-492    -24     2
```

Sample result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/06ea0/1).

Comment: It is useful for 10 warehouse

Comment: @DavidBeckham: Ofcourse, as I said, It can be used if you have a **known set** of values, no matter how many.

Comment: @DavidBeckham: Feel free to accept the answer if you are satisfied.